How do custom HTML tags interact with cloning a template?
Here's the test case that I'm confused with. In html (in the end of body):
<template id="test">
    <test-tag class="test-id"></test-tag>
</template>

In the script:
class TestTag extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("TestTag created");
    }
    get Property() : string {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

// in some function:
    customElements.define("test-tag", TestTag);
    customElements.whenDefined("test-tag").then(() => {
        console.log("test-tag defined");
        var tag = document.createElement("test-tag") as TestTag;
        console.log(tag.Property);

        var template = document.getElementById("test") as HTMLTemplateElement;
        var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true) as DocumentFragment;
        var tag2 = clone.querySelector<TestTag>(".test-id");
        if(tag2 == null){
            console.error("tag2 is null");
        } else {
            //customElements.upgrade(tag2);
            if(!(tag2 instanceof TestTag)){
                console.error("WTF?!"); //did not expect to be here
            }
            console.log(tag2.Property); //tag2.Property is undefined
        }
    });

The first tag object works as I expect. The second one doesn't: it seems that cloning the template creates a generic DOM element rather than an instance of my TestTag class.
To me it seems to be the main function of custom elements - to define necessary behaviour and reuse it while still describing complex divs with HTML markup rather than some ugly construction code of dozens createElement/appendChild calls. So it seems like I'm missing something obvious. Like maybe shadow DOM mechanic but customElements.upgrade() does nothing in this case.
My question is: if there's some well-known part of using custom elements I've missed then what is it; if not, what can be reasonably done to obtain a TestTag instance as tag2 value in the example above and why my example behaves the way it does?

worthy of reading here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template#avoiding_documentfragment_pitfalls

There is a difference between a Class Object and a DOM Element attached to the DOM


<template id="test">
  <test-tag class="test-id"></test-tag>
</template>

<script>
  class TestTag extends HTMLElement {
    get Property() {
      return "Hello";
    }
  }

  customElements.define("test-tag", TestTag);
  var tag = document.createElement("test-tag");
  var template = document.getElementById("test");
  var clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  var tag2 = clone.querySelector(".test-id");
  console.log(tag2.nodeName, tag2.constructor.name, tag2 instanceof HTMLElement, tag2 instanceof TestTag, tag2.Property);

  document.body.append(tag2); // MAKE IT DOM!!!
  console.log(tag2.nodeName, tag2.constructor.name, tag2 instanceof HTMLElement, tag2 instanceof TestTag, tag2.Property);

</script>



